# what wire do I need to hookup dual monitor to my computer

Tags: display

I have a 22inch monitor hooked up to my computer. I have another 14 inch monitor that I would like to hook up so that I have dual monitors.  I am not sure which wire do I need from newegg in order to do this.

I've taken some pics:

Pic 1: my computer (white port is 24 pins)

[image]

Pic 2: wire for my 22 inch monitor (currently this is hooked to my computer)

[image]

Pic 3: wire for 14inch monitor

[image]

Which wire should I buy?

Comment: Your pics didn't work.  Google `DVI` and `VGA` and see what connector your computer has.  If it has `DVI` and your 14" monitor is also `DVI` then get a `DVI` cable.  If it has `VGA` and your 14" monitor is also `VGA` then get a `VGA` cable.  If your computer has `DVI` and your monitor has `VGA` then you need to make sure your GPU `DVI` port can be adapted to `VGA` with the appropriate adapter.  If it can then you could get the adapter and and a `VGA` cable and you would be set.  If your computer has `VGA` and your 14" monitor has `DVI` then you are out of luck.

Comment: @typoknig: try to right-click and select "Open in new window/tab". 
@Omnipresent: your image hoster forbids direct embedding of images, replace them with links.

Comment: @whitequark: Actually, it's because he got the direct link under the copy-paste menu instead of grabbing it from the BBCode/HTML tag.

Comment: The cords are backwards from what I'd like... the 22inch would probably do a lot better with a DVI connectino, while the 14inch probably won't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just plug them in: everything is OK. Your video card (pic. 1) has one [VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) output (left) and one [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) output (right); you have one monitor with VGA interface (pic. 2) and one with DVI (pic. 3).